grid-template-rows hindering scroll functionality
I'm a beginner and can't understand for the life of me why when I implement grid-template-rows to define the size of my menu bar and content divs, that the content loses its existing scroll functionality.
This is when I add grid-template-rows to the body
Could someone help me understand why.
I tried template-rows, auto-rows, not sure what I'm missing.
edit: I've also tried re-wrapping the whole body. Kinda just stabbing in the dark now.
edit: once the re-wrap height goes over 700px, the scroll functionality stops.
https://codepen.io/Jago971/pen/YzMYYGW


body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: solid 1px;
    display: grid;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    border: solid 1px;
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}
li {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: scale, 0.25s;
}
li:hover {
    scale: 1.05;
    cursor: pointer
}
i {
    color: white;
}
#fadeTop {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
    border: solid 1;
    background-color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, white);
}
#fadeBottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
    border: solid 1;
    background-color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, white, transparent);
}
#tilesCarousel {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
#tilesCarousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none
}
.tileContainerWrap {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    display: grid;
}
.tileContainer {
    margin: 50px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.hiddenInfo {
    display: none;
}
.tile {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;

    font-family: Dosis;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 5px rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: scale, 0.25s;
}
.tile:hover {
    scale: 1.03;
    cursor: pointer
}
<ul>
<li class="menuOption">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
</li>
<li class="menuOption">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
</li>
<li class="menuOption">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
</li>
<li class="menuOption">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
</li>
<li class="menuOption">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-rotate-left"></i>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="tilesCarousel">
<div id="fadeTop"></div>
<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color5">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2021</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color1">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2022</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color2">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2023</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color3">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2024</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color4">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2025</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color5">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2026</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tileContainerWrap">
  <div class="tileContainer color1">
      <h1 class="hiddenInfo">2027</h1>
      <div class="tile">Jan</div>
      <div class="tile">Feb</div>
      <div class="tile">Mar</div>
      <div class="tile">Apr</div>
      <div class="tile">May</div>
      <div class="tile">Jun</div>
      <div class="tile">Jul</div>
      <div class="tile">Aug</div>
      <div class="tile">Sep</div>
      <div class="tile">Oct</div>
      <div class="tile">Nov</div>
      <div class="tile">Dec</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fadeBottom"></div>
</div>



